# Segmentation fault:11 MergeSort

Tags: c++, algorithm, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I try to implement the merge sort algorithm and I get a segmentation fault. Why? The error seems to be in the MergeSort function. The merge sort function (on the 2nd call) when should check only an array of 4 numbers (the length should be 4) shows the length = 27. Why? (tested on an array with 8 elements)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int n, A[1000];

void citire(int lungime) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lungime; i++) cin >> A[i];
}

void afisare(int lungime) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lungime; i++)
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    cout << '\n';
}

int lungime(int A[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (A[i]) i++;
    return i;
}

void Merge(int L[], int R[], int A[]) {
    int nL = lungime(L);
    int nR = lungime(R);
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < nL && j < nR) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            A[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            A[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < nL) {
        A[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < nR) {
        A[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}


void MergeSort(int A[]) {
    int n1 = lungime(A);
    if (n1 < 2) return;
    else
    {
        int mid = (int)n1 / 2;
        int L[mid];
        int R[n - mid];

        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
            L[i] = A[i];
        for (int i = mid; i < n; i++)
            R[i - mid] = A[i];
        MergeSort(L);
        MergeSort(R);
        Merge(L, R, A);
    }
}


int main() {
    cin >> n;
    citire(n);
    MergeSort(A);
    afisare(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I know it but I've changed to OSx developent environment and my debugger is not working I don't know why. I will set it up, but maybe I will find the answer here before I finish setting up the debugger

Comment: "as I am new to OSx c++ compiler and cannot debug the code" sounds like the perfect opportunity to learn!

Comment: good point here

Comment: `while (A[i]) i++;` will overrun your buffer `A` unless it's null terminated, which it's not guaranteed to be.

Comment: the lungime function is the length of the string and whis function works good. I've tested it on different arrays

Comment: @AndrewT the *caller* should specify the sequence length being sorted, which, btw, will *significantly* reduce your code complexity. Better still, swallow the C++ pill and use *iterators*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes made in this example. A[], L[], R[] are allocated using new. A[] is passed as a parameter. L[] and R[] are allocated in Merge(). Size and/or indices passed as parameters, and lungime() is no longer used to get size. Other changes noted in comments.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void citire(int A[], int lungime) {     // A is parameter
    for (int i = 0; i < lungime; i++) cin >> A[i];
}

void afisare(int A[], int lungime) {    // A is parameter
    for (int i = 0; i < lungime; i++)
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    cout << '\n';
}

// A, low, mid, end are parameters
// L and R allocated here
void Merge(int A[], int low, int mid, int end) {
    int sizeL = mid-low;
    int sizeR = end-mid;
    int *L = new int[sizeL];
    int *R = new int[sizeR];

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeL; i++)
        L[i] = A[low+i];                // A[low+i]
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeR; i++)
        R[i] = A[mid+i];                // A[mid+i]

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = low;          // k = low
    while (i < sizeL && j < sizeR) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            A[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            A[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < sizeL) {
        A[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < sizeR) {
        A[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    delete[] R;
    delete[] L;
}

// A, low, end are parameters
void MergeSort(int A[], int low, int end) {
    int sizeA = end - low;
    if(sizeA < 2)
        return;
    int mid = low + (sizeA / 2);        // mid = low + ...
    MergeSort(A, low, mid);
    MergeSort(A, mid, end);
    Merge(A, low, mid, end);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *A = new int[n];                // A is allocated
    citire(A, n);                       // A, n are parameters
    MergeSort(A, 0, n);                 // A, 0, n are parameters
    afisare(A, n);                      // A, n are parameters
    delete[] A;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"The lungime function is the length of the string and this function works good. I've tested it on different arrays".
Well, this is purely accidental; uninitialized memory can contain zeros, and provide the array terminator by accident.
If you want to keep the current design, you should:

- initialize A to zeros
- make sure that there are no more than 999 elements in the input stream,
- that no element has the value zero, as zero is reserved, and used as terminator, and
- define L and R (in MergeSort) one element longer, and initialize the last element to zero.

Unless there are overwhelming reasons for a "roll your own" sort solution, you might have a look at prefab sort support. The vector class in C++ offers just that.

Comment: I know that the vector class in C++ offers it but I am learning the algorithm and I am trying to implement it by myself

Comment: Which is a perfect reason for ryo. In this setting you might try to figure out how much stack space is consumed by the recursive MergeSort routine, and how this poses a limit on the size of the array that is to be sorted.